# can’t change password?

Tags: command-line, password, chromebook, password-recovery

Okay, so here is the problem. I am on chrome os and went through the process of installing Ubuntu through shell. But when it prompted me to create a password it would not let me! So I started Ubuntu anyway. Now I have a blank password and I can’t reset it! Help

Comment: @Nmath: There are 32 answers for the question that you link. Can you recommend just one of the answers or do you expect the OP to try each of the 32?

Comment: @C.S.Cameron  I would start with the top answer that has 915 votes with 99.9956% of those votes being upvotes.

Comment: Thank you @Nmath, That really helps. I would probably have started at the bottom of the page, that is where all the newer answers are.